# Cannot POST and DELETE based on Node.js tutorial on TutorialPoint

Tags: node.js, express

I am beginner on **Node.js** and try on using **express.js**. I follow the tutorial from **Tutorialpoint** to learn express.js. However, I have some trouble on **node.js restful api** session. Here is its link:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm

I follow this tutorial but get trouble on **POST** and **DELETE** HTTP methods. Here is their code:

**users.json**

```
{
   "user1" : {
      "name" : "mahesh",
      "password" : "password1",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 1
   },
   "user2" : {
      "name" : "suresh",
      "password" : "password2",
      "profession" : "librarian",
      "id": 2
   },
   "user3" : {
      "name" : "ramesh",
      "password" : "password3",
      "profession" : "clerk",
      "id": 3
   }
}
```

**POST method:** Cannot GET /addUser

```
var user = {
   "user4" : {
      "name" : "mohit",
      "password" : "password4",
      "profession" : "teacher",
      "id": 4
   }
}

app.post('/addUser', function (req, res) {
   // First read existing users.
   fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       data = JSON.parse( data );
       data["user4"] = user["user4"];
       console.log( data );
       res.end( JSON.stringify(data));
   });
})
```

**DELETE Method:** Cannot GET/deleteUser

```
app.delete('/deleteUser', function (req, res) {

   // First read existing users.
   fs.readFile( __dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
       data = JSON.parse( data );
       delete data["user" + 2];

       console.log( data );
       res.end( JSON.stringify(data));
   });
})
```

2 GET methods on this link works properly. Also, I don't know why I call POST and DELETE, the result prints GET to screen although I cannot call any GET methods. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Are you sure you have set form method as "post" for hitting the post route?

Comment: This tutorial only tells me to add http://127.0.0.1:8081/addUser to to see my result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting `Cannot GET/deleteUser` because you are hitting the api through a browser and the browser will always send a GET request. You should use something like POSTMAN to make POST request then you will be able to make post requests.